# 'Modernizr' is not defined / 'Modernizr' was used before it was defined

Tags: jquery, modernizr, jshint

I am using codekit to put together a few things.

1. jQuery
2. Modernizr
   (prepended to the script below)

So I'm just troubleshooting some things and getting back to basics on a project. As is, jsHint returns the error

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {

'Modernizr' is not defined.
```

and so then I add in:

`/*global Modernizr:true */`

but then, I get -

`Modernizr' was used before it was defined.`

```
(function($){

// =========================================

  $(document).ready(function() {
  // ===============================


    if (Modernizr.touch) {

      alert('touch');

    } else {

      //alert('no-touch');

    }

  // ===============================
  });

// =========================================
})(jQuery);
```

The alert works, and it's adding the class to my < html > etc... but this is driving me mad.

What am I doing wrong? (besides using codekit instead of brunch)

Comment: weird. when i try the same with jslint, i don't get any complaints about modernizer.

Comment: also, when i input your code + the comment here: http://www.jshint.com/ it doesn't give me any warnings.

Comment: It could be this new codekit 2. I have a feeling it is doing crazy stuff because this project is giving me tons of trouble on every front.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check whether the issue with JSHint itself or your configuration/editor is to paste your code on jshint.com. With your code, I assume you're either not providing the full listing or your editor does something weird. Because `'Modernizr' was used before it was defined.` appears only when `latedef` option is turned on **and** you're accessing your variable before its declaration.